# Get all localization strings using Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

How I can get all of the localization strings of a file's languages?

When I use `Lang::get();`, I get an error. I need to get the group key. But how I can get all strings of the languages, along with the groups and keys?

Comment: What do you mean by "I get error"? Can you share that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `config/filesystems.php` file add this:

```
'lang' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => base_path('resources/lang/en'),
    ],
```

Then you can use this disk to iterate over all the files, and get the content out of each of them:

```
foreach (Storage::disk('lang')->files('') as $file)
{
    dd(Lang::get(explode('.php', $file)[0])); // you can use something else then explode to get just the name of the file without the extension
}
```